# Error: cannot join on columns: index out of bounds

Tags: r, inner-join

I'm trying to inner join two datasets, rate and state.regions. R gives me an error message:

> cannot join on columns 'StateCode' x 'abb': index out of bounds.

I have no idea how to fix it. Is there anybody can help with this problem? Thanks!

```
stateRates <- rate %>%
filter(IndividualRate<9000 & BusinessYear==2016) %>%
group_by(StateCode) %>%
summarise(MedianIndividualRate = median(IndividualRate),
value = median(IndividualRate)) %>%
inner_join(state.regions, by=c("StateCode"="abb"))
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: That's the kind of error you get if one of the variables doesn't exist, so make sure `abb` is in your second dataset exactly as you've written it.

Comment: I'm sure `abb` is in the state.regions dataset.@aosmith